# URL for Google cloud storage in JAVA on localhost (testing)

Tags: google-cloud-storage

This is partly related to use within the testing (localhost, from Eclipse) environment. I am using GCS with com.google.cloud.storage.Storage. using JAVA in the server (and GWT in the client).

Ultimately, I want to have a URL of an image store as a com.google.cloud.storage.Blob passed from the server to GWT to be displayed with MaterialImage.

One problem when running under localhost (app engine) I noticed that the Blobs are being stored actually on the GCP in my Blob storage (meaning not locally/temporarily for testing on localhost.

This ultimately causes problems when trying to use,storage.signedUrl, for example:
URL signedUrl = storage.signUrl(BlobInfo.newBuilder("bucket","filename").build(), 2,
             TimeUnit.DAYS);
here I get the error '*Signing key was not provided and could not be derived'....

Ulitimately, I want/need a solution that works the same on localhost (for testing) and on the app engine in GCP (meaning, for example, I don't want to have a reference to my local key to solve the problem above).

Bottom line:

1. Can I have temporarily stored cloud storage blobs on localhost? and how?  I think might solve my issues...
2. How can I generate a URL (not necessarily signed) that I can give to something like MaterialImage in the client. I don't necessarily want to transfer bytes to the client (though I will do this for text files).

Thanks for any help or hint... (once again JAVA solution)

Answer (score 0):

You have the [getServingUrl()](http://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/images/#transform-images) method that allows returns the URL that serves the image. 
Using this method you can generate an URL for an image that is stored in Cloud Storage or Blobstore.

Comment: Yes, this returns a URL, but unfortunately it does not work inside MaterialImage (or I suppose image)... When this link is used the browser, for example, it goes directly to download object, the browser does not 'render' the object... I suspect this is why it doesn't work within Image.